# Joomla SobiPro search results in a 404

Tags: joomla, sobipro

(Apologies if I'm breaking any community guidelines here with this question, I just don't know how else to ask?)

I've recently migrated one of my Joomla sites from 2.5 to 3+ and one of the most important components I use on the site is SobiPro.

I've upgraded SobiPro to the latest version as well and made sure that everything is in order.

Now this is where I'm having a problem. On just one single section, when I do a search I get a 404 when going to the results page and for the life of me I don't know what is wrong.

This is not happening on any other section, just this one. I've checked all settings and I've literally run out of ideas as to where to look and what to do to get to the bottom of this.

I'm happy to provide further info, I just don't know what to provide?

Any help that could possibly point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen in various ways and the fix usually tends to be the following.

Turn "Search Engine Friendly URLs and Use URL Rewriting" off.

Navigate the site on the frontend, to the area affected.

Then turn "Search Engine Friendly URLs and Use URL Rewriting" on.
May need to clear the cache afterwards, and make sure your hosting doesnt have some extended cache on, via php.ini.

Comment: Thanks @norcal. I'm willing to try anything at this point. I'll give this a go and give you some feedback!

Comment: So I tried this, and it's definitely an issue with the "Search Engine Friendly URLs" and the "Use URL Rewriting". Turning these off sorted out the problem however turning them back on the issue reoccurs, even after forcing all caching off. That said, I couldn't find any cache setting at all in the php.ini so wasn't actually sure what to clear there, if anything at all.

Comment: If you are on a non windows server/machine...change your htaccess.txt to .htaccess then it should work with sef and rewriting on.

Comment: oh also, delete your redirect links that may be associated with it.

Comment: Thanks @norcal johnny - good point on the windows server which is valid, however in this case specifically I'm working on a linux machine.

Comment: How about the deletion of redirecting links :)